# Expose Java class as SOAP WebService - how?

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I am looking for a framework to turn given Java class into WebService (may be with some limitations on method parameters etc)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [axis2](http://ws.apache.org/axis2/), or [xfire](http://xfire.codehaus.org/).  I'm sure there are other ways also, but these are the two that I've used.

Answer (score 0):

The de-facto standard for this is Apache Axis: http://ws.apache.org/axis/ and http://ws.apache.org/axis2/